# haproxy ssl keeps failing

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, haproxy

I have haproxy setup in a 6 server node web application setup. 2 front end servers. 2 web servers. 2 database servers.

I recently added ssl certificates and redirection for all the sites running on the servers. We run Drupal multiside setup. So each site has its own apache config and conf file on the web servers.

The setup seems to work but what happens is SSL redirection fails after a certain amount of time (usually 1 few hours) and I have to keep restarting haproxy to fix it. I suspect either its a setup issues with my haproxy or I am going about this the wrong way.

Below is my haproxy config file with accounts and ip's munged.

Anyone able to give me any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

```
    global
        log         127.0.0.1 local2
        chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
        pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
        maxconn     4000
        user        haproxy
        group       haproxy
        daemon
        stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

    defaults
        mode                    tcp
        log                     global
        option                  httplog
        option                  dontlognull
        option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
        option                  redispatch
        retries                 3
        timeout http-request    10s
        timeout queue           1m
        timeout connect         10s
        timeout client          1m
        timeout server          1m
        timeout http-keep-alive 10s
        timeout check           10s
        maxconn                 3000

    frontend  web-front *:80
        acl url_static       path_beg       -i /static /images /javascript /stylesheets
        acl url_static       path_end       -i .jpg .gif .png .css .js
        option               abortonclose
        option               http-keep-alive
        default_backend             web

    frontend  web-front-ssl *:443
        acl url_static       path_beg       -i /static /images /javascript /stylesheets
        acl url_static       path_end       -i .jpg .gif .png .css .js
        option               abortonclose
        option               http-keep-alive
        default_backend             web-ssl

    listen stats *:9000
        maxconn     500
        mode http
        log global
        stats enable
        stats refresh 30s
        stats hide-version
        stats show-node
        stats uri /stats
        stats auth ******:*******

    backend web
        balance     roundrobin
        stick-table type ip size 1m expire 1h
        stick on src
        server  web01 10.10.10.17:80 check maxconn 1000
        server  web02 10.10.10.18:80 check maxconn 1000
        option abortonclose
        option http-keep-alive

    backend web-ssl
        balance     roundrobin
        stick-table type ip size 1m expire 1h
        stick on src
        server  web01 10.10.10.17:443 check maxconn 1000
        server  web02 10.10.10.18:443 check maxconn 1000
        option abortonclose
        option http-keep-alive
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean by "ssl redirection fails", but since you are saying that this happens after 1 hour, then this is probably about the "expire 1h" in your configuration.
Try to adjust that parameter accordingly.